# Int [][] searching for joint ints

Tags: java, arrays, int

I have a structure `int[][]`, with fixed size. It is filled with natural numbers. An example:

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   1 2 6 9 0 3 4
>   3 1 3 4 5 6 0
>   1 2 3 0 2 1 1
>   1 2 0 0 0 1 0

My aim is to check how many 'circles' of zeros in this structure I have. In this example the answer should be 4.
**Edit**
A circle is a structure that contains all joint zeros. What does it mean? These are the zeros that can be reached from one zero going up, down, left or right (no diagonals are taken into account).
Example solution:
First circle:

> **0 0 0 0 0 0 0**
>   1 2 6 9 **0** 3 4
>   3 1 3 4 5 6 0
>   1 2 3 0 2 1 1
>   1 2 0 0 0 1 0

Second one:

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   1 2 6 9 0 3 4
>   3 1 3 4 5 6 **0**
>   1 2 3 0 2 1 1
>   1 2 0 0 0 1 0

Third one:

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   1 2 6 9 0 3 4
>   3 1 3 4 5 6 0
>   1 2 3 **0** 2 1 1
>   1 2 **0 0 0** 1 0

Fourth one:

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   1 2 6 9 0 3 4
>   3 1 3 4 5 6 0
>   1 2 3 0 2 1 1
>   1 2 0 0 0 1 **0**

Comment: And what is that "circle"?

Comment: One circle contains all joint zeros

Comment: If you'd like a moment from our days, please take a moment from your day to adequately describe your vernacular. What is a "circle"? What are "joint zeros"? Don't assume we are familiar with your specific domain.

Comment: @SpecialSauce please see the edit, hope it kind of clarifies

Comment: Thanks for the edit, yet I am still confused, could you "bold" the 4 joint ints you are talking about.

Comment: @CedricMartens please see the new edit

Comment: Thanks for editing: it is now clear you mean "contiguous regions".

Comment: @SpecialSauce Yes, I'm corry for being confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example algorithm is a fairly straightforward.

1. start at location unchecked before.
2. find a zero along with neighboring zeros.
3. change the value of found zeros to 1. [like flood-fill]
4. increment the counter.
5. if not all positions checked go to 2.
6. else: report the result.

What you might want look into is Flood fill. Like here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

---

Alternatively - more fun.

Define a **circle** class that is a set of pixel[x,y]

1. find all individual zeros location [x,y]
2. let each of the individuals zero be an individual "circle"
3. merge adjacent circles together into bigger "circles"
4. keep merging (3-4) no progress.
5. report the result.

In this case proper sorting will be the key ingredient.
You will need function that checks if two circles are adjacent.
It gives much more fun!.

Comment: That's what I thought first! But it gave me too much of memory overhead because of recursion. Then I took the non recursive one, which did not work well

Comment: Ok Maciej. I gave you another alternative one :).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a [blob detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection), an image processing algorithm that finds neighboring pixels sharing a property (like greyscale value).
OpenCV has a built-in [blob detector](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html?highlight=blob#SimpleBlobDetector%20:%20public%20FeatureDetector). A tutorial on the usage can be found [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/).

You may also check [connected component labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling). You could implement it from the given pseudo-code (your intention to avoid external libraries) and it does not contain recursion (your comment to Vito's answer).

Comment: Well, first of all, thank you for your help. However, I am only working with simple int[][] and I should not import any external libraries. I should have a direct function that takes as an argument this int[][] and returns a single int meanint number of "blobs"